# Rewriting URLs in Joomla Component

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a trouble in mod_rewrite redirect. I want to create friendly SEO links for my component. Now linkk looks like that:

```
http://www.mytestsite.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=show_posts&evid=11&Itemid=200&year=2013&month=10&day=15&title=this-is-really-test-article-here&uid=43840300d283724e77d5f33f19780f36&catids=15|16|17|18&filter_reset=1
```

I want to have:

```
http://www.mytestsite.com/posts/200-this-is-really-test-article-here
```

where first part of URL is itemid (200), and after article title.

How can i do that?

Comment: Have a read of this: http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla, this is done in the administrator control panel by editing the site configuration (Site...Global Configuration). Click on the SEO tab and check the desired options, save and you're done.

If you need more options, try installing an [SEO extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/alt-text/19121)

Answer (score 0):

Do make sure that you have a .htaccess file in the root of your web server home directory.

Also make sure that adequate file permissions are set, so that php/joomla can write to .htaccess and add mod_rewrite rules. I would recommend setting .htaccess file permission to 644. If that doesn't work, come back and ask again!

For Search Engine Keyword selection, this tutorial should be sufficient **(skip to step 3)**: http://moz.com/blog/seo-your-joomla-website-in-11-super-easy-steps

A useful link to test if mod_rewrite is enabled on your webserver: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_check_if_mod_rewrite_is_enabled_on_your_server